# hide a salesforce tab based on parameters

Tags: apex, visualforce, managed-package, controller, tab

I have a salesforce tab from a managed package which shows VF pages. I want to show and hide the tab based on a field on the current User profile, is this possible?

Comment: I guess you could, but you probably shouldn't. Normally one solves these problems with profile settings and permission sets. For a managed app i think a permission set is the way to go since you can update those after the app has been installed. Is there a specific reason you'd want to do this with a field on the user profile?

Comment: Actually, that filed has a value which defines whether a user can access that tab or not and it is dynamically changed. If a user is inactive for 30 days the field changes and he should not be able to see the tab and when administrator approves his reactivation request he should be able to see it again (typically a workaround to save licenses ) .

Comment: I think you may be able to just remove the user licence for your managed package instead. I think that would make the tab invisible, or at least save the licence. Then the admin can add the user again if they wish to do so? I think the licences are stored in this object: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_userpackagelicense.htm